# How can I completely remove the hide/done button from a keyboard in a swift app?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uikeyboard, uitextviewdelegate

I have a following code:

```
textView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
```

that makes my keyboard look like this:

[image]

but I would like to get rid of the done/return button and achieve this:

[image]

what's the best way of doing it in `swift`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot achieve this by changing the return button type, instead you need to change the keyboard type. In order to change the keyboard type to match the one you posted that you would like to match, use the `twitter` keyboard type.

**Swift 2**

```
textView.keyboardType = .Twitter
```

**Swift 3**

```
textView.keyboardType = .twitter
```

Comment: Have you  tested it ?

Comment: Yes I have. If you would like to see a description of all the different keyboard types check this out: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uikeyboardtype